# Datatables very slow load on Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I have to get data from fingerprint machine. Everything in my code run and works, but if I show all employee data, it loads very slow.
I have create datatables by codeigniter and ajax call to view. My code like below

```
// Datatables Variables
        $draw       = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
        $start      = intval($this->input->get("start"));
        $length     = intval($this->input->get("length"));
        $year       = $this->input->post("year");
        $month      = $this->input->post("month");
        $dept       = $this->input->post("dept");
        $where      = $year.'-'.$month.'-';
        $shifts     = $this->m_general->get_data('tb_shift')->result();
        $rows       = $this->m_employee->attendance($where)->result_array();
        if($dept=='5'){
            $pin_emp    = $this->m_general->get_data('tb_employee')->result();
        }else{
            $pin_emp    = $this->m_general->check_data('tb_employee',array('emp_dept'=>$dept))->result();
        }
        $loc_machine= $this->m_general->get_data('tb_pkm')->result();
        $roaster    = $this->m_employee->list_schedule_emp($where)->result_array();
        $holiday    = $this->m_general->get_data('tb_holiday')->result();
        $total_days = tglakhir($year,$month);
        $dates      = array();
        $people     = array();
        $data       = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if (empty($row['date']) || empty($row['pin'])) {
                continue; // no date or sn, nothing to print for this row...
            }
            // in array assures unique values
            if (!in_array($row['date'], $dates)) {
                $dates[] = $row['date'];
            }

            // this may seem convoluted, take your time to understand
            $people[$row['date']][$row['pin']] = $row;
            $array_emp[$row['date']][$row['pin']][] = $row;
        }

        foreach ($roaster as $rs) {
            if (empty($rs['date']) || empty($rs['id_nip'])) {
                continue; // no date or sn, nothing to print for this row...
            }
            // this may seem convoluted, take your time to understand
            $get_rs[$rs['date']][$rs['id_nip']] = $rs;
            $dt_rs[$rs['date']][$rs['id_nip']][] = $rs;
        }

        foreach($pin_emp AS $q){
            $array_pin[]=$q->emp_pin;
            $details[$q->emp_pin] = $q;
        }

        foreach($holiday AS $hday){
            $get_hday[$hday->date_holiday] = $hday;
        }

        foreach($loc_machine AS $list_machine){
            $lm[$list_machine->id_machine] = $list_machine;
        }

        for($m=1; $m <= $total_days; $m++){
            if($m<10){
            $m = '0'.$m;
            }else{
                $m = $m;
            }
            $date[]=$m;
        }

        foreach($shifts AS $shift_e){
            $array_shift[$shift_e->id_shift] = $shift_e;
            $ar_shift[]=$shift_e->id_shift;
        }

        foreach ($array_pin AS $id){
            $name       = $details[$id]->emp_name;
            $shift      = $details[$id]->emp_shift;
            $id_machine = $details[$id]->emp_reg_sn;
            if(isset($lm[$id_machine])){
                $loc_machine= $lm[$id_machine]->pkm_name;
            }
            $date_range = array();

            foreach($date AS $date_col){
                $day = date('D', strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date_col));
                $today = date('Y-m-d');
                $full_day   = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date_col;
                $s_in       = '';
                $s_out      = '';
                $time_in    = '';
                $time_out   = '';
                $t_in       = '';
                $t_out      = '';
                $finger_tap = '';
                $diff_in    = '';
                $diff_out   = '';
                $diff       = null;
                $diff2      = null;
                $late       = '00:00:00';
                $r          = $date_col;
                $title      = '';
                $date_holiday= '';
                if (ISSET($get_hday[$full_day])==TRUE) {
                    $date_holiday = $get_hday[$full_day]->date_holiday;
                    $title        = $get_hday[$full_day]->note_holiday;
                }
                foreach ($dates as $key) {
                $shift_detail= $array_shift[$shift]->code_shift;
                if(isset($get_rs[$full_day][$id]['id_shift_emp']) && $get_rs[$full_day][$id]['id_shift_emp']!=''){
                    $shift          = $get_rs[$full_day][$id]['id_shift_emp'];
                    $shift_detail   = $array_shift[$shift]->code_shift;
                }
                    if (isset($people[$key][$id]['date']) && $people[$key][$id]['date'] == $key) {
                        foreach ($array_emp[$key][$id] AS $dtl){
                            if(isset($get_rs[$key][$id]['id_shift_emp']) && $get_rs[$key][$id]['id_shift_emp']!=''){
                                $shift  = $get_rs[$key][$id]['id_shift_emp'];
                            }
                            $shift      = $dtl['emp_shift'];
                            $date_time  = $dtl['date_time'];
                            if(($shift==5)OR($shift==7)OR($shift==9)OR($shift==11)OR($shift==12)OR($shift==14)){
                                $r = $date_col+1;
                            }
                            if(substr($key,8,2)==$date_col){
                                $status_code= $dtl['status_code'];
                                $status_note= $dtl['att_status'];
                                $first_in   = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date_col.' '.$array_shift[$shift]->first_check);
                                $last_out   = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$r.' '.$array_shift[$shift]->last_check);
                                $shift_in   = $array_shift[$shift]->in_shift;
                                $shift_out  = $array_shift[$shift]->out_shift;
                                $s_in       = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$shift_in);
                                $s_out      = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$shift_out);
                                $finger_tap = strtotime($date_time);
                                $shift_detail= $array_shift[$shift]->code_shift;
                                foreach($ar_shift AS $id_shift){
                                    if ($shift==$id_shift) {
                                        $currdiff = abs($finger_tap - $first_in);
                                        if (is_null($diff) || $currdiff < $diff) {
                                            $diff = $currdiff;
                                            $time_in = date('H:i:s',strtotime($date_time));
                                            $t_in    = strtotime($date_time);
                                            if(($t_in-$s_in)>0){
                                                $diff_in = gmdate('H:i:s',$t_in-$s_in); 
                                            }else{
                                                $diff_in = $late;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        $currdiff2 = abs($finger_tap - $last_out);
                                        if (is_null($diff2) || $currdiff2 < $diff2) {
                                            $diff2 = $currdiff2;
                                            $time_out = date('H:i:s',strtotime($date_time));
                                            $t_out    = strtotime($date_time);
                                            if(($t_out-$s_out)>0){
                                                $diff_out = $late;
                                            }else{
                                                $diff_out= gmdate('H:i:s',$s_out-$t_out);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(($shift==5)OR($shift==7)OR($shift==9)OR($shift==11)OR($shift==12)OR($shift==14)){
                                if ($day==$r) {
                                    $shift_out  = $array_shift[$shift]->out_shift;
                                    $s_out      = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$r.' '.$shift_out);
                                    $finger_tap = strtotime($date_time);
                                    foreach($ar_shift AS $id_shift){
                                        if ($shift==$id_shift) {
                                            $currdiff2 = abs($finger_tap - $last_out);
                                            if (is_null($diff2) || $currdiff2 < $diff2) {
                                                $diff2 = $currdiff2;
                                                $time_out = date('H:i:s',strtotime($date_time));
                                                $t_out    = strtotime($date_time);
                                                if(($t_out-$s_out)>0){
                                                    $diff_out = $late;
                                                }else{
                                                    $diff_out= gmdate('H:i:s',$s_out-$t_out);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Belum hadir"><i class="material-icons col-green">check_box_outline_blank</i>'.$shift_detail.'</a>';
                            if($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date_col < $today){
                                $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Alpha"><i class="material-icons col-red">fiber_manual_record</i>'.$shift_detail.'</a>';
                            }
                            if(($day == 'Sun') OR ($day == 'Sat')){
                                $status='<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-md bg-red waves-effect" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Libur">off</button>';
                            }
                            if($date_holiday == $full_day){
                                $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.$title.'"><i class="material-icons col-red">today</i>OFF</a>';
                            }
                            if($time_in!=''){
                                if($time_in==$time_out){
                                    $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Absen"><i class="material-icons col-red">brightness_6</i>'.$shift_detail.'</a>';
                                }
                                if ($status_code!='') {
                                    $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.$status_note.'"><i class="material-icons col-orange">sim_card_alert</i>'.$shift_detail.'</a>';
                                }
                            }
                            if($time_in!=$time_out){
                                $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Complete"><i class="material-icons col-green">check_box</i>'.$shift_detail.'</a>';
                            }
                            if($time_in=='00:00:00'){
                                    $status = '<a href="javascript:change_status_att(\''.$id.'\',\''.$name.'\',\''.$full_day.'\')" class="btn btn-xs btn-dino" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.$status_note.'"><i class="material-icons col-orange">sim_card_alert</i>'.$shift_detail.'</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $date_range[] = $status;
            }
            $first = array(
            '<a href="javascript:view_att_emp(\'details\',\''.$id.'\',\''.$year.'\',\''.$month.'\')">'.$id.'</a>',
            $name,
            $loc_machine
        );
            $data[] = array_merge($first,$date_range);
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $draw,
            "recordsTotal" => '',
            "recordsFiltered" =>'' ,
            "data" => $data
        );
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($output));
}
```

This code runs and works, but need about 10 second for load.
Can somebody help Me what I have to do to be fast this load?

UPDATE

after I analysis my code, the slow load data because datatables say "data was truncated". But when I load on small data(filtered), It was fine.

problem still same when I get all data from database.

Comment: Am I seeng that right? a `foreach`, inside a `foreach`, which itself is inside another `foreach`? No wonder it runs slowly.

Comment: Because I need to do that for my result. That's why I ask here maybe someone can help me or give idea for my code.

Comment: That was the idea, you need to change your code so that it's not a loop inside a loop inside a loop inside a loop inside a loop... Or are you saying that someone should rewrite your code for you in a faster way?

Comment: Exactly No. Maybe someone give easy looping becuse I need all looping was created. cmiw.

Comment: Answer to the comment you maid on my reply: so I guess it’s a problem with your database, not with CodeIgniter nor PHP. You may improve your question by removing some tags and adding the SQL tag (if your database is SQL, or wathever adapted) and put the results of the requests directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster, you first need to know what is slow. To do that, you need to use debugging tools, like [this one](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=debug#CI_Email::print_debugger) and [timestamps](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.time.php).

Then, once you get logs with the duration of your processes, you can analyze it to know which part of your code is slow.

Then, try to optimize it. And if you can’t, edit your question to focus on the slow part or post a new one.

Comment: Please use comments for comments. Your rep is high enough to use comments, and this is not really an answer to OP problem

Comment: after I analysis my code, the slow load data because datatables say "data was truncated". But when I load on small data(filtered), It was fine.

problem still same when I get all data from database.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Actually my rep wasn’t high enough when I posted this ^^’ but I agree with you.